# Initialising a dictionary from text file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a complex hierarchical python dictionary like this

```
      dict = {
               "key1":{"key11":{"a"},"key12":{"b"}},
               "key2":{"key21":{"c"},"key22":{"d"}},
               "key3":{"key31":{"e"},"key32":{"f"}}
             }

      print dict["key2"]["key21"]
```

The output of this code snippet is "c", so the hierarchical dictionary is interpreted correctly. Now, instead of hard code this hierarchical dictionary in code, I want to read it from a file and assign it to a dictionary object. That's to say, I will create a dict.txt file with the following content:

```
             {
               "key1":{"key11":{"a"},"key12":{"b"}},
               "key2":{"key21":{"c"},"key22":{"d"}},
               "key3":{"key31":{"e"},"key32":{"f"}}
             }
```

Of course, I will then run to read the stream of the file

```
            stream = open("dict.txt", "r")
```

Then, is there any convenient method in python that allows me to easily assign the content in the stream to a dictionary object `dict` (not as string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you simply put the entire `dict = {...}` into the text file, name the file `something.py`, and then `import something` and use it directly as `something.dict`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure it's in that exact format, that is valid JSON, so you can use `json.load(f)` to load and parse it.

JSON is much pickier than Python though (eg it chokes on trailing commas, and doesn't accept single quotes), so you might need to use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(stream.read())
```

But your data is not just a nested dict, rather it has sets as values (at least if one interprets it as Python syntax), which `ast.literal_eval` can't handle.

From what I understand, that is not a valid JSON for the same reason.